# Putting items in a sinusoidal arrangement

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like to optimize the second line in my for loop(var phase). I believe moving parts of it outside of the loop would optimize performance. What can I move outside the for loop to improve performance?

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
var phase = Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop / 1250) + (i % 5));
//var phase = 0.31456656061611776 + (i % 5);
items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the major part of the slowdown will be applying the style.

Otherwise you can pregen an array with the possible phases:

```
var phases = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    phases[i] = Math.sin((document.body.scrollTop / 1250) + i );
}
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var phase = phases[i%5];
    //var phase = 0.31456656061611776 + (i % 5);
    items[i].style.left = items[i].basicLeft + 100 * phase + 'px';
}
```